# what permission needed to acces AdminRecycleBin.aspx

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-permissions

we need to give acces to the page 'AdminRecycleBin.aspx'
without giving a full control to the site , what i should give a kind of permission to let a group have acces to the 'AdminRecycleBin.aspx' using powershell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Site Owners will have an access to 1st level recycle bin.

Primary and Secondary Site Collection Administrators can see the Administrator recycle bin as well as user recycle bin.

You can read more about managing the Recycle bin of SharePoint site in below article:

[Manage the Recycle bin of a SharePoint site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-the-recycle-bin-of-a-sharepoint-site-8a6c2198-910e-42dc-9a9c-bc5bc4f327da).

Comment: the problem here is i should not give the user The permission required is Site Collection Owner. all i need is that page access. any idea

Answer (score 1):

The permission required is Site Collection Owner.

Comment: the problem here is i should not give the user The permission required is Site Collection Owner. all i need is that page access. any idea